# Why do the creators of this dashboard multiply bytes by 8 to get bits? Isn't it the other way around?

Tags: networking, network-speed, grafana, telegraf

To monitor a server we have imported a dashboard for Grafana. This uses Telegraf and InfluxDB as collector and database.

When certain graphs needed to be adjusted, I noticed that in the network speed queries, the bytes received (bytes_recv) are multiplied by 8, but the units on the graph itself are displayed in bits.

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(mean(bytes_recv),1s)*8 as "in" FROM "net" WHERE host =~ /$server/ AND interface =~ /$netif/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval), * fill(none)
```

According to my understanding is: 8Bit = 1Byte. According to this, if the data is available as bytes, it would have to be divided by 8 to get bits, if the graph should display bits.

Furthermore (if I am not mistaken):
*Megabit = Mb
Mebibit = Mib
Megabyte = MB
Mebibyte = MiB*

Refering to this, the unit on the graph seems to be megabit right?
Do I understand something fundamentally wrong or was the "*" simply confused with the "/"?

[Screenshot of the Grafana Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHOI4.png)

Comment: You are correct 1 byte = 8 bit. Just look at the values of 1 and 8 and then try your divide approach to get from byte to bits, you will recognize that you will fail to do so: 1/8 is not 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your math is slightly incorrect. `1 byte = 8 bits`. So far, so good. Given that, a byte is bigger than a bit (specifically eight times bigger). We know this because it takes eight bits to consume the same space a byte would. So we can re-write the equation as `1 byte = 8 * 1 bit`. Or, alternately, `1 bit = ⅛ byte`. So, if we have, say, `X bytes`, but we want bits, we multiply by `8`, giving us the equation `bytes * 8 = bits`. As a general rule, if you go from a big unit of measurement to a smaller one (like bytes to bits), you multiply.